# clang rejects a template `/` operator but gnu c++ accepts it

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

In the context of unit management for scientific programming, I am managing the following class:

```
template <class UnitName>
class Quantity 
{
  double value;

public:

  Quantity(double val = 0) : value(val) {}

  Quantity(const Quantity &) {}

  Quantity & operator = (const Quantity &) { return *this; }

  double get_value() const noexcept { return value; }

  operator double() const noexcept { return value; }

  template <class SrcUnit>
  Quantity(const Quantity<SrcUnit> &)
  {
    // here the conversion is done
  }

  template <class SrcUnit>
  Quantity & operator = (const Quantity<SrcUnit> &)
  {
    // here the conversion is done
    return *this;
  }

  template <class TgtUnit> operator TgtUnit() const
  {
    TgtUnit ret;
    // here the conversion is done
    return ret;
  }

  template <class U, class Ur>
  Quantity<Ur> operator / (const Quantity<U> & rhs) const
  {
    return Quantity<Ur>(value / rhs.value);
  }
};
```

Although the class is much more complex, I think I put enough information in order to describe my problem:

Now consider the following code snippet:

```
struct km_h {};
struct Km {};
struct Hour {};

Quantity<km_h> compute_speed(const Quantity<Km> & dist,
                             const Quantity<Hour> & time)
{
  Quantity<km_h> v = dist/time;
  return v;
}
```

This code is accepted by `gnu c++` compiler and it runs well. The last template operator `/` is called.

But it is rejected by `clang++` compiler (v 3.8.1) with the following message:

```
test-simple.cc:53:26: error: use of overloaded operator '/' is ambiguous (with operand
      types 'const Quantity<Km>' and 'const Quantity<Hour>')
  Quantity<km_h> v = dist/time;
                     ~~~~^~~~~
test-simple.cc:53:26: note: built-in candidate operator/(__int128, unsigned long long)
test-simple.cc:53:26: note: built-in candidate operator/(unsigned long, long double)
```

So my questions would be: why `clang++` rejects it? is a valid code? or `gnu c++` should reject it?

In the case where the code would be valid, how could modify it in order to `clang++` accept it?

Comment: How would the type `Ur` be deduced from the expression `dist/time`?

Comment: [OT]: You may look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_units.html

Comment: All this boils down to the danger of using casting operators.  The point being that even if code were accepted, are you sure which function or set of functions would actually be called?   Programmers have been burned by this too often, where they expected one set of functions to be called, but under the covers, something else is being done.  If you got rid of the `double()` casting operator, you would probably have no issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that clang is right to reject your code<sup>†</sup>, but gcc doesn't actually do what you want (both `dist` and `time` are implicitly convertible to `double`<sup>‡</sup> and gcc believes the builtin `operator/(double, double)` is the best viable candidate). The problem is, you wrote:

```
template <class U, class Ur>
Quantity<Ur> operator / (const Quantity<U> & rhs) const
```

What is `Ur`? It's a non-deduced context - so attempting to invoke this operator as simply `dist / time` is a deduction failure. Your candidate is never considered. In order to actually use it, you'd have to explicitly provide `Ur` like so:

```
dist.operator/<Hour, km_h>(time); // explicitly providing Ur == km_h
```

Since that's awful, you can't have `Ur` be deduced as a template argument - you have to provide it yourself as some metafunction of the two units:

```
template <class U>
Quantity<some_mf_t<UnitName, U>> operator/(Quantity<U> const& ) const;
```

with `some_mf_t` is to be defined.

---

<sup>†</sup>You have both `operator double()` and `template <class T> operator T()`, which means that all the builtin `operator/`s are equally viable candidates (they're all non-template, exact matches).

<sup>‡</sup>Having `operator double()` sort of defeats the purpose of writing type safe units, no?

Comment: Or with C++14 he might be able to just make the return type `auto`

Comment: @GuyGreer We still need to compute the return type. Using `auto` doesn't solve anything.

Comment: If the conversion to `double` is the best conversion sequence, then would that mean that given `f(double, double); f(double, int); Quantity<Km> a;`, `f(a, a)` should pick the first overload? GCC agrees with clang there that it's ambiguous, and that makes me think clang is right on the `/` operator too.

Comment: @hvd Oh, I see. We prefer the non-template to template on the *function*, not the conversion sequence (I thought we might prefer `operator double()` since it's non-template but that is specified nowhere). I'll fix.

Comment: Right. I found it now in [over.ics.rank]p3.2, that's the place that defines when one user-defined conversion is better than another, and it doesn't treat template conversion operators as less important than non-template conversion operators.

Comment: Thanks @Barry for your answer and all who have commented. In effect, the last operator was not called at all. And yes, casting to `double` is a bad idea and I think that was the way as `gnu` compiler accepted the code. I just solved the problem by writing, such as you suggested, meta functions deducing the return type resulted from combining two different `Quantity` objects.